# Sitecore JSS installation error

Tags: jss

I am getting the below error once I installed the Sitecore JSS server packages Preview 4. I have follwed the same steps mentioned in https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install

> The controller for path '**/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss**' was not found or does not implement IController.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss' was not found or does not implement IController.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path
> '/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss' was not found or does not implement
> IController.]
>
> [ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller:
> 'LayoutService'.  The context item is:
> '/sitecore/content/Careers/Home'.  The current route url is:
> 'sitecore/api/layout/{action}/{configuration}'. ]
> Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
> requestContext, String controllerName) +172
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
> +268    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +95
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +923    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157

Comment: A few questions: What version of Sitecore are you using?
Do you have any other modules installed? Where/how are you encountering this error, e.g. are you browsing directly to the layout service endpoint (as the docs suggest) or are you seeing this error in some other context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like some kind of custom routing setup may be conflicting with Layout Service's routing registration.

Layout service (App_Config/Sitecore/LayoutService/*.config) patches its route registrations after the `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc` pipeline processor, so if some other custom routing causes this patch to fail, the LS route may not be registered correctly.

Using the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page will let you diagnose this issue and see the interactions between custom routing. If the `Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterRoutes, Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc` pipeline processor does not go before the `InitializeRoutes` pipeline processor, the LS will not register correctly.

Comment: I am seeing the Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterRoutes, Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc pipeline registered before InitializeRoutes pipeline processor. But I am still have the issue.

Comment: Is this a fresh Sitecore installation or an existing installation with customizations? Try removing customizations and re-adding them to isolate the one causing issues.

Comment: It is a fresh installation of Sitecore 9 version. But, I have done few customization before I install this package. Let me try your suggestion and keep you posted. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: It worked now after i had removed my custom configs and DLLs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check your configs, for the better understanding how the configs work, check this link.

https://doc.sitecore.com/SdnArchive/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites.html

- **modules_website** - reserved for modules usage, front-end side
- **Website** - default front-end web site, also used for WebEdit, Debug, Preview

The patch works in orders, so If you want to patch your jss before `website` use `patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']` this way it wont conflict your existing site.